# Add PHP Configure Command on Mac OS X

Tags: php, macos

I want to add "*--with-freetype-dir=/usr/ --enable-gd-native-ttf" to PHP Configure Command for using "imagettftext()*" method.

But I cannot find php configure command on **Mac OS X**.

How to change php configure command ?

**OS:** Mac OS X Yosemite

**PHP Version:** PHP 5.5.31

Comment: What? Do you mean `./configure`? That only exists when you are compiling the PHP binaries. If not, ignore me :)

Comment: @LFlare I mean `php -i | grep 'Configure Command'` or Configure Command in <?php phpinfo(); ?> page.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. In this case, you cannot edit it, as it's set during compile time. To get what you want, you will have to compile PHP from source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by changing system PHP to installing php.

```
brew tap homebrew/homebrew-php
brew update && brew upgrade
brew install php55
Change apache httpd LoadModule php
export PATH="$(brew --prefix homebrew/php/php55 -)/bin:$PATH" added to ~/.profile
```

Answer (score 0):

./configure command is to compile PHP from source.

That means, you will replace php shipped with OSX with a custom version: follow the documentation here: http://php.net/manual/en/install.macosx.compile.php

You should use XAMPP or MAMP, instead of trying to compile PHP yourself. They are shipped with everything you need, and are easy to install and configure.